# AJAX success data not showing correctly

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

For some reason the following ajax success function is not working

**What am I trying to do?**

- Press button
- Get flavour list
- Display list in a pop up or div (neither are working)

**The AJAX call:**

```
$('#datatable').on( 'click', '.recipeFlavours', function (e) {
    var token = '<?php echo json_encode($token); ?>';
    var flavourList = true;
    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
    var rowSelector;
    var li = $(this).closest('li');

    if ( li.length ) {
     rowSelector = table.cell( li ).index().row;
    }
    else {
      rowSelector =  $(this).closest('tr');
    }

    var recipeID = table.row(rowSelector).data().recipe_id; 


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controllers/recipeControl.php",
        data: { token: token, recipeID: recipeID, flavourList: flavourList },
        success: function(data){

            $(".success_container").html(data);
            console.log(data);

            var popup = '<div class="modal fade" id="notes-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="notes-modal-container"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h1></h1><h3>Recipe Flavours</h3><br>' + data + '</div></div></div>';




    $(popup).modal('toggle');

        },
    });
    return false;
});
```

**The Controller:** Works fine as `PHP` without the `json_encode()`

```
/**
    GET RECIPE FLAVOURS FOR POPUP
*/

if(isset($_POST['flavourList'])) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' && isset($_POST['token']) && json_decode($_POST['token']) === $_SESSION['token']){

        //echo json_encode($Recipes->getRecipeFlavours($recipeid));
            $html = "<div>";
            $content = $Recipes->getRecipeFlavours($_POST['recipeID']);
            foreach($content as $value) {
                $html .= $value['recipe_flavour_name'].$value['recipe_flavour_percent'];
            }
            $html .= "</div>";
            echo json_encode($html);

    }
}
```

**The function to get the flavours and percents:**

```
/**
    GET RECIPE FLAVOUR LIST
*/

public function getRecipeFlavours($recipeid) {
    $query = 'SELECT recipe_flavour_name, recipe_flavour_percent FROM recipe_flavours WHERE recipe_flavour_recipe_id = :recipeid';
    $stmt = $this->queryIt($query);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':recipeid',$recipeid);
    if($this->execute()) {
        return $this->resultset();
    }
}
```

**As PHP this is the output:**

[image: [img]]

**As the success data in AJAX:**

[image: [img]]

Comment: Remove json_encode()

Comment: You don't need to json encode data if your response is pure html. And specify in your ajax request the [type of response](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) even if there's an intelligent autoguessing.

Comment: You guys are awesome, I did try that earlier but for some reason it showed no data at all, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove json_encode() because you are using HTML as Datatype for ajax

```
 if(isset($_POST['flavourList'])) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' && isset($_POST['token']) && json_decode($_POST['token']) === $_SESSION['token']){

        //echo json_encode($Recipes->getRecipeFlavours($recipeid));
            $html = "<div>";
            $content = $Recipes->getRecipeFlavours($_POST['recipeID']);
            foreach($content as $value) {
                $html .= $value['recipe_flavour_name'].$value['recipe_flavour_percent'];
            }
            $html .= "</div>";
            echo $html;

    }
}
```

Comment: You are using pure HTML so don't need to apply json_encode()

Answer (score 1):

You are using json_encode while returning the response in controller, but not decoding while process the response in javascript.

So please remove json_encode and try. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $(".success_container").html(obj);
            console.log(obj);

            var popup = '<div class="modal fade" id="notes-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="notes-modal-container"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h1></h1><h3>Recipe Flavours</h3><br>' + obj + '</div></div></div>';
$('#test1').html(popup);

alert(popup)
```